# Is passing Main Window pointer to other class a good idea?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to share with you my code so I can get a feedback about my solution.
Problem: I need a separate class for managing calculations in program and for dealing with GUI-stuff.
Proposed solution:
Reemiting signals given by MainWindow, so they are visible in "calculation module" class.

main:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "calcmodule.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    calcModule cM(nullptr,&w);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

calcModule.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>

class calcModule : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit calcModule(QObject *parent = nullptr,MainWindow *MainWindowPointer=nullptr);

private:
    bool valState;
    MainWindow *Mw;
public slots:
    void changeValState(bool m_valState);
};

#endif // CALCMODULE_H
```

MainWindow.h:

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

signals:
    void sigMyButton(bool stateVal);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

calcModule.cpp:

```
#include "calcmodule.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

calcModule::calcModule(QObject *parent,MainWindow *MainWindowPointer) : QObject(parent), Mw(MainWindowPointer)
{
 connect(Mw,&MainWindow::sigMyButton,this,&calcModule::changeValState); 
}

void calcModule::changeValState(bool m_valState)
{
    valState=m_valState;    
}
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug()<< "Emitting signall now!";
    emit sigMyButton(true);
}
```

How it should work:
For testing purpouse I have just a GUI with a button that changes the state of bool variable inside calcModule class for "true". The way I have done this, presented above, works just fine for my and even more complex things can be done like adding more "slave classes" governed by GUI - MainWindow class. Even though it works I am not sure if for some reasons ( I am worried about memmory as I just use reference to mainWindow) is an acceptable solution.

Will be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Your approach, handling GUI events and calling working methods, is good. It's called "event-driven" programming. It's the best way to go for GUI apps. Just a note: call `connect` from the button constructor, not at the working class/method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your objects model is.  Referencing to MainWindow instance, belonging to the main thread (GUI), from an object of an other thread must be used with care.
Calling GUI functions directly from others thread can lead to application crash.

If you consider your MainWindow is a view part (GUI) and the other object (calcModule) is a worker, this worker should belong to a separated thread (working thread) in order to avoid GUI blocking when performing long operations.
At higher abstraction level, MainWindow and calcModule are two objects staying in two different threads, one listens to an event (changeValState) from other,
you can connect them together without passing its pointer:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    calcModule cM;
    
    //move calModule to other thread 
    //....
    //Notify user action to calcModule
    QObject::connect( &w, &MainWindow::sigMyButton, &cM, &calModule::changeValState );
    
    //Notify the calc value to user
    QObject::connect( &cM, &calModule::calcValueChanged, &w, &MainWindow::updateCalcValue  );
    
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for Your answer. I will definitely try this. One question: when I tried to QObject::connect(blablablabla) in main I got a lot of errors, that is why it all ended up in constructors of those objects. Do You know what could have been wrong in such case? Cause I bet that Your solution works.